# How to link a project to two different versions of the same C static library?

Tags: c, linker, package, static-libraries

I am working on a complex C ecosystem where different packages/libraries are developed by different people.

I would like to create a new project named `foobar`. This project *uses* two libraries, the library `foo` and the library `bar`.

Unfortunately, `bar` does not require the same version that `foo` requires. Both use `say` so there is a conflict.

If all the packages are on Git with submodules, the `foobar` project cannot be built when cloned recursively because two `say` functions exist in different translation units. So the `submodule` strategy doesn't work.

My question is: how is it possible to manage *one* project that uses *two* different version of the *same* static library (`*.a`)?

### Structure

```
          foobar
            |
       .----'----.           <---- (require)
       v         v
      foo       bar
(v1.0) |         | (v2.0)
       '-> say <-'
```

The project foobar require the library `foo` and the library `bar`, both of these libraries uses the `say` package: `foo` requires version 1 and `bar` requires version 2.

### Packages

#### say

```
// say.h
void say(char *);
```

#### foo

```
// foo.c
#include "say.h"

void foo(void) {
    say("I am foo");
}
```

#### bar

```
// bar.c
#include "say.h"

void bar(void) {
    say("I am bar");
}
```

#### foobar

```
// main.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo"
#include "bar"

int main() {
    foo();
    bar();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: For anyone to provide a meaningful answer, you'll probably need to provide a lot more detail about how the different libraries are all compiled, how they're all linked into libraries, and how they're linked into executables.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, for now, the libraries are yet not libraries. They are just source-code. I am thinking about static libraries because I target embedded bare-metal systems.

Comment: If they are in source code, just change the name of one of the functions.

Comment: What tool chain? GCC, with the `ld` linker?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield *just change the name of one of the functions.* Or update `foo` to use version 2.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, probably IAR and Keil

Comment: Keil has a [--partial](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlink/armlink_pge1362075540343.htm) switch. Some [2009 documentation](http://supp.iar.com/FilesPublic/UPDINFO/004916/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf) for IAR does not show such a switch, but it suggests that other tools can produce files conforming to the Embedded Application Binary for Interface for ARM (AEABI), so you could investigate whether GCC’s linker could be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linkers typically have a mode in which they perform a partial link, which resolves references that can currently be resolved and produces an object module ready for further linking instead of a finished executable file.

For example, the GCC linker `ld` has a `-r` switch that allows this. Using this switch, and possibly others, you could link `foo.o` with one library to make `foo.partial.o` and separately link `bar.o` with another library to make `bar.partial.o`. Then you could link `foo.partial.o` and `bar.partial.o` with each other, the main program, and any other libraries and object modules needed.

This can work for static libraries, where the code for each library is included in the resulting executable or object file, and the references to its symbols are fully resolved. For shared dynamic libraries, there may be problems, since dynamic libraries require references to be resolved at run time, and the linker and executable file format might or might not support the ability to distinguish symbols of the same name in different versions of one library.

Comment: That's very interesting. I didn't know about the `-r` switch. This is perhaps a good answer to my question.

Comment: The answer skips one step?  Using objcopy to localize symbols.

Comment: @hunter_tech: I have performed the link operations described in this answer without using `objcopy` and see no reason it would generally be needed.