# C++: Linking to two versions of opencv. How can I tell the linker to pick a specific verion

Tags: c++, opencv, linker

## Description

I have the following problem:

- I am developing the library libmy_code.so
- I need to link against a closed source library libclosed_source.so **over which I have no control**
- libclosed_source.so is *statically* linked against opencv 3.2.0
- libclosed_source.so has exported *all* symbols (also those from opencv 3.2.0 which I do not want)
- My library libmy_code.so also needs the newer version opencv 3.4.11
- I use CMake as the build system

See the following diagram

```sh
                                           +-------------+
                                      +--->|libmy_code.so+<-------+
                                      |    +-------------+        |
                                      |                           |
                    Statically linked |                           |dynamically linked
                                      |                           |
                                      |                           |
                                      |                           |
                                      |                           |
                                      |                   +-------+-----------+
                                      |                   |libclosed_source.so|
                                      |                   +-------------------+
                                      |                           ^
                                      |                           | Statically linked
                                      |                           |
                                  +---+---------+           +-----+------+
                                  |OpenCV 3.4.11|           |Opencv 3.2.0|
                                  +-------------+           +------------+
```

### Problem

- My library libmy_code.so uses cv::resize. The CMake build system correctly locates cv::resize in the headers of OpenCV 3.4.11 (I use find_package(OpenCV) and point it to the opencv 3.4.11 install).
- However the linker links cv::resize to libclosed_source.so (which contains the Opencv3.2.0 version of cv::resize statically).
- My build system runs in a docker container which definitely does not have opencv 3.2.0.
- The closest question I have found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881047/how-to-link-a-project-to-two-different-versions-of-the-same-c-static-library)

How can I tell the linker not to linker opencv functions libmy_code.so to libclosed_source.so but directly to Opencv 3.4.11 ??

Comment: If you're using CMake you can use HINTS to direct it to pick a specific location when importing a library - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075371/cmake-find-library-custom-library-location

Comment: Similar problem solved, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783761/how-do-i-link-different-versions-of-the-same-library-in-g?rq=1

Comment: @Den-Jason I only have OpenCV 3.4.11 in the build container. OpenCV 3.2 enters in by being statically linked to  libclosed_source.so. Will HINTS still work??

Comment: @MilindDeore Thanks this looks good

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I link different versions of the same library in g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783761/how-do-i-link-different-versions-of-the-same-library-in-g)

Comment: @AdrianMole : Sorry for the late answer. The suggested link from @Milind Deore didn't help, I got `ld --relocatable -o libclosed-source-prelinked.so libclosed-source.so ../../opencv-3.2.0/lib/libopencv_core.a 
ld: attempted static link of dynamic object ` libclosed-source.so'`

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

My solution to the problem is to load libclosed_source.so dynamically per dlopen with RTLD_DEEPBIND|RTLD_LOCAL into libmy_code.so. This way libmy_code.so can use opencv 3.4.11 and libclosed_source.so can still use opencv 3.2.0.

The executable that was linked against libmy_code.so had to be compiled with -fPIC to prevent problems with libstdc++, more to that in
[Weird interaction of RTLD_DEEPBIND, Position independent Code (PIC) and C++ STL (std::cout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68223646/weird-interaction-of-rtld-deepbind-position-independent-code-pic-and-c-stl)